# Photo changer loop

Tags: python, image

I just started Python a few days ago, and I haven't programmed much before. I know my code is terrible; however, I would like someone to look it over. What I'm trying to do is create a photo "loop" that changes my Windows 7 login screen. I had a batch file doing it, but even though my code is crappy it does the job way better.

I'm using two separate scripts, and if possible I would like to combine them. Renamer.py only runs when new photos are added. It sets up the file names for LoginChanger.py. `LoginChanger` is picky in the filenames, but `Renamer` doesn't change the photos in a loop. So I have to use `Renamer`, then `LoginChanger` to loop the photos.

**Renamer.py**

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:        Renamer
# Purpose:     Renames all .jpg's in a dir from 0 - n (where "n" is the number of .jpg's.)
#              This is to be used in conjunction with loginchanger.py
# Author:      Nathan Snow
#
# Created:     13/01/2012
# Copyright:   (c) Nathan Snow 2012
# Licence:     <your licence>
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

count = 0
count2 = 0
list1 = []
list2 = []

for filename2 in os.listdir('.'):
        if filename2.endswith('.jpg'):
            list1.append(filename2)
            while count < len(list1):
                os.rename(filename2, str(count)+"old.jpg")
                count += 1

for filename3 in os.listdir('.'):
        if filename3.endswith('.jpg'):
            list2.append(filename3)
            while count2 < len(list2):
                os.rename(filename3, str(count2)+".jpg")
                count2 += 1
```

**LoginChanger.py**

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:        LoginChanger
# Purpose:     This is to be used after renamer.py. This loops the properly named
#              .jpg's in a "circle" first to last, 2-1, 3-2, ..., and changes
#              0 to BackgroundDefault.jpg.
# Author:      Nathan Snow
#
# Created:     13/01/2012
# Copyright:   (c) Nathan Snow 2012
# Licence:     <your licence>
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

count = 0
list1 = []
list2 = []
list3 = []

for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    if filename.endswith('.jpg'):
        list3.append(filename)
        list3len = len(list3)
        list3len = list3len - 1
    if filename.startswith('BackgroundDefault'):
        os.rename('BackgroundDefault.jpg', str(list3len)+'.jpg')

for filename2 in os.listdir('.'):
    if filename2.endswith('.jpg'):
        list1.append(filename2)
        while count < len(list1):
            jpg = str(count)+'.jpg'
            oldjpg = str(count)+'old.jpg'
            os.rename(str(jpg), str(oldjpg))
            count += 1

for filename4 in os.listdir('.'):
    if filename4.startswith('0'):
        os.rename('0old.jpg', 'BackgroundDefault.jpg')

count = 1
count2 = 0

for filename3 in os.listdir('.'):
    if filename3.endswith('.jpg'):
        list2.append(filename3)
        while count < len(list2):
            newjpg = str(count2)+'.jpg'
            oldjpg = str(count)+'old.jpg'
            os.rename(str(oldjpg), str(newjpg))
            count2 += 1
            count += 1

print ('Created new login background')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could avoid continuously renaming all files by overwriting just `BackgroundDefault.jpg` file instead e.g., `change-background.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import bisect
import codecs
import os
import shutil

BG_FILE = u'BackgroundDefault.jpg'
db_file = 'change-background.db'
db_encoding = 'utf-8'

# read image filenames; sort to use bisect later
files = sorted(f for f in os.listdir(u'.')
               if f.lower().endswith(('.jpg', '.jpeg')) and os.path.isfile(f)) 
try: files.remove(BG_FILE)
except ValueError: pass # the first run

# read filename to use as a background from db_file
try:
    # support Unicode names, use human-readable format
    with codecs.open(db_file, encoding=db_encoding) as f:
         bg_file = f.read().strip()
except IOError: # the first run
    bg_file = files[0] # at least one image file must be present

# change background image: copy bg_file to BG_FILE
tmp_file = BG_FILE+'.tmp'
shutil.copy2(bg_file, tmp_file)
# make (non-atomic) rename() work even if destination exists on Windows
try: os.remove(BG_FILE)
except OSError: # in use or doesn't exist yet (the first run)
    if os.path.exists(BG_FILE):
       os.remove(tmp_file)
       raise
os.rename(tmp_file, BG_FILE)

# write the next filename to use as a background
next_file = files[bisect.bisect(files, bg_file) % len(files)]
with codecs.open(db_file, 'w', encoding=db_encoding) as f:
     f.write(next_file)
```

Comment: I copied this and it worked the first time. Then it said it couldn't change the background image because the file was already there. I had to remove a ")" from "files = sorted(glob.glob(u'*.jpg')))" to get it to work as well. I really appreciate the help though, Thanks.

Comment: @Jedimaster0: I've fixed the code. I don't use Windows so it is untested.

Answer (score 3):

- Your variable names are pretty bad: `filename1`, `filename2`, `filename3`, ... is bad, use something more meaningful.
- There is no need to use different loop variables in consecutive loops. Use `filename` everytime.
- You need to move the `#!/usr/bin/env python` shebang line to the first line of the file or it won't work at all.
- You have unnecessary `str()` calls in `os.rename(str(oldjpg), str(newjpg))` - both variables are already strings.